# Check if text starts with blank space

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-validation

This question is not specifically for django but python as a whole. What I want to do is, when the user submits, how would I check to see that the title should not start with " " (space). It can start with any other character but not space.

views:

```
def admin_page_create(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
        title = request.POST.get("title", "")
        if title != '' or title != <<<regex or function() to check title does not start with a blank space>>>:
            Page.objects.create(title=title, user=request.user)
            data = "Created a new page: '" + title + "'."
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
        else:
            data = 'You gave us a blank title. Please try again.'
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: Do you mean `title.startswith(' ')`?

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the first character of a string using its index, which is `0`. Then, just compare it to `" "` or use [`.isspace()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isspace.htm).

```
if title[0] != " ":
if not title[0].isspace():
```

Another and probably more elegant solution, as stated by @Andy and @Daniel, would be to use [`.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).

```
if not title.startswith(" "):
```

You might be interested by [`.strip()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) which removes spaces characters from start and end of a string or even [`.lstrip()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lstrip.htm) more specifically.

Comment: or maybe `lstrip` in this case?

Comment: @JulienSpronck Thank you, I added it to the answer.

Comment: I changed the view to `if title != '' or title.startswith(' '):`. But if I post title as "     asdf", it still goes to the `else` section of the code.

Comment: @Benjamin You have to add  `not` and `and`. This means, "if title does not start with " " then proceed". `if title != '' and not title.startswith(' '):`

Comment: @Benjamin Do not forget to use `and` instead of `or`, you have to check for the two conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method:

```
title.startswith(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the first character is a space:

```
if title.startswith(" "):
```

If you want to check if the first character is any whitespace, you can do this:

```
import re # regular expression module
if re.match(r"\s", title): # match() matches only at beginning of subject text.
                           # \s is any whitespace
```

or this:

```
if title != title.lstrip(): # lstrip removes whitespaces at the left (hence the "l")
```